# Bash command not found and having trouble with a method

Tags: java

I am having trouble with method F. A, B, C, D all work. For method F I keep On getting bash command not found.

Method A prints the smallest number of the 3  double inputs.

Method B averages three int inputs.

Method C takes the first digit in an int.

Method D takes the last digit in an int.

Method E counts the amount of digits there are in an int.

Method F is supposed to find the amount of letter is in a string so, "!!!fd!!!" will only print out 2(it is incomplete right now)

My main concern is: when I run the code and It ask for a string, and the user types in the code, I keep getting bash: whatTheUserTypes: comand not found. I do not know what is wrong nor do I know how to acomplish method F's goal.

import java.util.Scanner;

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

//uses part A, prints smallest number
    System.out.println("Give me 3 doubles with a space in between each.");

        double a = input.nextDouble();
        double b = input.nextDouble();
        double c = input.nextDouble();

    double buc = smallest(a, b, c);
        System.out.println(buc + " is the smallest of the 3.");
                System.out.println("");


//uses part B, takes avg of 3 ints
    System.out.println("Give me 3 integers with a space in between each.");

        int e = input.nextInt();
        int v = input.nextInt();
        int g = input.nextInt();

    int avg = average(e, v, g);
        System.out.println(avg + " is the average of the 3 numbers.");
                System.out.println("");


//uses part C, D, and E, prints first digit and below the last digit, and how many digits there are.
    System.out.println("Give me an integer.");

        int n = input.nextInt();

    int fstdig = firstDigit(n);
    int lstdig = lastDigit(n);
    int numdig = digits(n);
        System.out.println(fstdig + " is the first digit in the number.");
        System.out.println(lstdig + " is the last digit in the number.");
        System.out.println("There are " + numdig + " digits in this number.");
                System.out.println("");

//usses f
    System.out.println("Give me a string.");

    String word = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("litarly a test" word);


    

  }
  
  //A
  public static double smallest (double a, double b, double c)
  {
    if (a < b && a < c){
        return a;

    }
      
    else if (b < a && b < c){
        return b;
    }     
    else
        return c; 
  }
  
  
  //B
  public static int average (int e, int v, int g)
  {
    return((e * v * g) / 3);
  }
  
  
  
  //C
    public static int firstDigit  (int n)
  {
     while (n > 9) {
        n /= 10;
    }
    return n;
  }


  //D
  public static int lastDigit  (int n)
  {  
    return Math.abs(n) % 10;
  }


  //E
  public static int digits (int n)
  {  
      String numberString = Integer.toString(n);
      int numbers = numberString.length();
        return numbers;
  }


  //F
  public static String countLetters(String word) 
  {
        return word;
  }
  
  
  //G
  
  
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you actually exited your app and then typed `whatTheUserTypes` at the bash prompt, resulting in `whatTheUserTypes: command not found`. PS the average of a, b, and c is not `(a * b * c) / 3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that your program is exiting before you expect it to.  The reason for that is that after you've taken integer input with `input.nextInt`, and then you want to take String input with `input.nextLine`, you have to make this call twice, throwing the first result away.  The reason for this is that you have to read the EOL character that followed the last set of numbers that the user typed in.  Then you can read the next line of input, which processes the text that the user entered along with the EOL that comes after it.

I don't know what you're talking about with the Bash thing, but my guess is that you don't realize that your program has exited, and so you are entering something that you think is being read by your program, and instead, the Bash shell is trying to process what you've typed.

So to be clear, try this for your "F" part:

```
//usses f
input.nextLine(); // burn the EOL from the last line of integers input
System.out.println("Give me a string.");
String word = input.nextLine();
System.out.println("litarly a test: " + word);
```

NOTE: The last line above had a syntax error in it.  You were missing the `+`.

Comment: Thanks, that helped